# EF Core generating reverse query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

There are 4 tables:

**UploadDate**

```
Id 
Description
```

**UploadType**

```
Id 
Description
```

**UploadStatus**

```
Id 
Description
```

**UploadDetail**

```
Id
UploadDateId (FK)
UploadTypeId (FK)
UploadStatusId (FK)
OtherFields..
```

**UplodeDate** *(data)*

```
1    Aug-2018
2    Sep-2018
3    Oct-2018
4    Nov-2018
5    Dec-2018
6    Jan-2019
```

**UplodeType** *(data)*

```
1    Partner
2    Retail
3    Customer
```

**UplodeStatus** *(data)*

```
1    Uploaded
2    Processing
3    Successful
```

**UplodeDetail** *(data)*

```
Id    UploadDateId     UploadTypeId    UploadStatusId    other fields
1     1                1               3                 ...
2     1                2               3                 ...
3     2                2               3                 ...
4     2                1               3                 ...
5     1                3               3                 ...
6     2                3               2                 ...
7     3                2               1                 ...
8     4                2               1                 ...
9     4                2               3                 ...
```

What I am trying to do it get the months for which upload is successful for *all upload types*

The query

```
var list = await _iContext.UploadDate.Where(e => e.UploadDetails.All(o => o.UploadStatusId == (byte)EnumType.UploadStats.Successful)).Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

So, from `UploadDate` I am getting where all the entries in `UploadDetails` are successful. It should give me `Aug-2018`. But it is giving `Dec-2018` and `Jan-2019`

I checked in `SQL Profiler`, and it is generating the following query...

```
SELECT DISTINCT [e].[Id], [e].[Description]
FROM [UploadDate] AS [e]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [UploadDetail] AS [o]
    WHERE ([e].[Id] = [o].[UploadDateId]) AND ([o].[UploadStatusId] <> CAST(3 AS tinyint)))
```

Basically filtering out everything that is `NOT` successful, which technically is the `reverse` of what I want it to generate, something like...

```
SELECT DISTINCT [e].[Id], [e].[Description]
FROM [UploadDate] AS [e]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [UploadDetail] AS [o]
    WHERE ([e].[Id] = [o].[UploadDateId]) AND ([o].[UploadStatusId] = CAST(3 AS tinyint))).
```

Also, if I ran the above query (just above, not the one generated by `EF Core`, I do get `Aug-2018`, which is the intended result.

So, why is `EF Core` generating the query in reverse of what I am intending to write? or have I written a totally wrong query itself?

Comment: EF Core generated query is correct for `All` operator (yours is an equivalent of `Any` and will match [1,2,4]). It gives you [1,5,6], isn't it? And the problem is the inclusion of 5,6?

Answer (score 1):

Both queries return incorrect results.

The EF Core generated SQL query returns [1, 5, 6].

The hand written SQL query (which is the equivalent of using `Any` instead of `All` and would have been also generated by EF Core if you do so) is returning [1, 2, 4].

And the desired result is [1].

First, it's a well known fact that

```
All(condition)
```

is the same as (equivalent of)

```
!Any(!condition)
```

Second fact is (and it can easily be seen) that both expressions return `true` when the sequence is empty (has no elements). Which is technically correct - all (zero in this case) elements match the condition. Or there is no element not matching the condition.

But doesn't work in your case because what you actually want is to *"get the months for which **upload exists and** upload is successful for **all** upload types"*, which is expressed as:

```
.Where(e => e.UploadDetails.Any()
    && e.UploadDetails.All(o => o.UploadStatusId == 3))
```

or "exists successful upload and does not exist unsuccessful upload", expressed as:

```
.Where(e => e.UploadDetails.Any(o => o.UploadStatusId == 3)
    && !e.UploadDetails.Any(o => o.UploadStatusId != 3))
```

Both these conditions will produce the desired behavior. However, they will generate 2 correlated subqueries to perform the check.

If you want to perform the check with just one correlated subquery (which doesn't guarantee the query will be faster - needs to be measured), you can use the following trick:

```
.Where(e => e.UploadDetails.Min(o => o.UploadStatusId == 3 ? 1 : (int?)0) == 1)
```

It utilizes the fact that `Min<int?>` function returns `null` when the sequence has no elements. This, plus the condition logic inside ensures that it will return `1` only when there are elements matching the condition and no elements not matching it. Which is exactly what we need.